# composer package testing bootstrap

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, bootstrapping

I've written a package and as part of the development proccess I want to run unit tests on it. This basically means I need a bootstrap file to register the autoloader for my package.

Any package I look at doesn't have a specific bootstrap file, thus I don't quite understand how the developers are testing their own packages.

This is my directory structure

```
src
.CompanyName
..PackageName
...Class 1
...Class 2

tests
.Class1Test
.Class2Test

composer.json
phpunit.xml.dist
```

Now if I run `phpunit` inside the root directory, all my tests say `\\CompanyName\\PackageName\\Class1` wasn't found. Which is legite, since nobody had them included. So the question is - **How and when do I include my classes**.

---

Looking at a [random packages](https://github.com/illuminate/cache/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist) I can see they rely on `vendor/autoload.php`, but I don't have this vendor dir. Should I run `composer install` to have it created ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I've figured the answer.
Composer provides it's own autoloader I could use.

1. Run `composer install` or `composer update` in the project root. This will create the `vendor` dir with composers `autoload.php` file.
2. Add `vendor` dir to `.gitignore` along with `composer.lock`
3. In `phpunit.xml.dist` specify composer's autoloader as the bootstrap file

Example `phpunit.xml.dist` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
        >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Your package's test suit">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

Notice the bootstrap entry there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should run `composer update`. It is not harmful to try since everything is put into /vendor/ which you can later delete.